# Dom::Interval function in Matlab Error

Tags: matlab, variables, operators, intervals

I am trying to plot `f(x)=sin(x)` in Matlab, but am having trouble defining my variable x as the interval [0,pi/2]. I have:

```
x1 = Dom::Interval([0], [1])
y1 = cos(x1)
plot(x1,y1)
```

However, the interval function in Matlab returns as an unexpected Matlab operator.

Comment: `Dom::Interval` is MuPAD code, not Matlab-Code. Take a look at the documented examples for the `plot` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dom::Interval` is part of the MuPad interface.  Simply create a numeric array from 0 to `pi/2` and plot the `sin` of the result.

```
x1 = linspace(0, pi/2);
y1 = sin(x);
plot(x1, y1);
```

[`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) generates a numeric array with a default amount of 100 points linearly spaced from 0 to `pi/2`.  You can override the amount of points by specifying a third element... something like:

```
x1 = linspace(0, pi/2, 300);
```

This creates 300 points.  Play around with the third parameter.  The more points you have, the more smooth the plot will be as the default method of plotting things in MATLAB is to just join the points together with straight lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that before, and it was giving me an error. I tried again with a higher number of intervals as you suggested and it worked.